# How can I load Doctrine entities from another repository, inside a shared Symfony bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a generic PHP repo which contains a number of Doctrine entities:

```
src
    Entity
        Foo.php
        Bar.php
```

I've created a shared Symfony bundle which requires this repo in its `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "myorg/entities": "dev-master"
},
```

How can I register the entities in this Symfony bundle, so that they're immediately made available to any project which includes it? I'd like to avoid the parent project having to explicitly list every entity in its `orm` config.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion better to register Doctrine ORM mappings pass. So your entities will be registered on compile.

```
namespace My\AppBundle;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MyAppBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $namespaces = ['My\AppBundle\Entity'];
        $directories = [__DIR__ . '/Entity'];
        $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createAnnotationMappingDriver($namespaces, $directories));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergei. Are you suggesting I define my generic PHP repo's namespace in the `$namespaces` variable?

Comment: Yes, define namespace and create bundle class. Then your bundle can be registered in AppKernel and it will register entities automatically.

Comment: Sorry Sergei, I need some clarification. Should `$namespaces` be set to that of my bundle, and `$directories` set to my generic PHP repo's entity directory?

Comment: `$namespaces` and `$directories` both should contain paths/namespaces to your entities. If your Foo.php and Bar.php will have namespace `src\Entity` it should be set to `$namespaces`. Same for `$directories` - path to your Foo.php and Bar.php

Comment: Thank you. So `$directories` will contain a path to my vendor directory?

Answer (score 0):

just use the @Repository annotation

for example:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="myorg\entities\Repository\FooRepository")
```